# Preselect option with first of array using v-for and v-model

Tags: vue.js, select

I am trying to preselect the first element option using v-for. I could set the data -> SelectedMonth to "12 måneder" - however the data will be dynamic.

I have tried using :selected(index === 0), however, that does not work with v-model.

```
        <select class="period-control" v-model="selectedMonth">
          <option
            v-for="(period, price) in car.months"
            v-bind:key="price"
            v-bind:value="period.month"
          >{{ period.month }}</option>
        </select>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedMonth: ""
  };
},
asyncData(context) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        car: [
          {
            id: "1",
            brand: "VW",
            model: "Transporter",
            variant: "Sport",
            thumbnail:
              "http://pluspng.com/img-png/cargo-van-png-van-png-transparent-image-1878.png",
            mprice: "2700",
            dpayment: "5400",
            months: [
              { month: "12 måneder", smprice: "1500" },
              { month: "24 måneder", smprice: "2500" },
              { month: "36 måneder", smprice: "3500" }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            brand: "Nissan",
            model: "Tekna",
            variant: "Sport",
            thumbnail:
              "http://pluspng.com/img-png/cargo-van-png-van-png-transparent-image-1878.png",
            mprice: "3000",
            dpayment: "5400",
            months: [
              { month: "12 måneder", smprice: "1500" },
              { month: "24 måneder", smprice: "2500" },
              { month: "36 måneder", smprice: "3500" }
            ]
          }
        ].find(el => el.id === context.params.id)
      });
    }, 1500);
  });
}
```

The expected result is "12 Måneder" in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

how about setting the value of `selectedMonth` in asyncData directly ?

```
  asyncData(context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const car = ...
      const selectedMonth = car.months[0].month;
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          car,
          selectedMonth
        });
      }, 1500);
    });
  }
```